# Wait for clickable element to become visible--Chromedriver

Tags: c#, powershell, selenium-chromedriver

below is a part of my code: It is designed to click on a button after it is visible.
This takes a different amount of time so i just implemented a wait for 10 seconds.

Is there a way i can make this more dynamic so the click is done right after it is visible?

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards

```
#go to the uploadtab
---------------------
$searchBtnIris = $driver.FindElementByXPath('//*[@id="menuFormHome:j_id44_body"]/ul[3]/li[4]/a')
Write-Host "Den ID van de zoekknop is $seachBtnIris"
$searchBtnIris.Click();

Start-Sleep -s 10

#click add button and select file to upload
-------------------------------------------
$searchBtnIris = $driver.FindElementByXPath('//*[@id="uploadFormPanel:upload:flashContainer"]')
Write-Host "Den ID van de zoekknop is $seachBtnIris"
$searchBtnIris.Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a *guess*

```
while (-not ($searchBtnIris)) {
    try {
        $searchBtnIris = $driver.FindElementByXPath('//*[@id="uploadFormPanel:upload:flashContainer"]')
    }
    catch {
        Write-Verbose "Element not found"
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100            
    }
}

Write-Host "Den ID van de zoekknop is $seachBtnIris"
$searchBtnIris.Click();
```

Comment: Hi

this returns: Exception calling "Click" with "0" argument(s): "stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Comment: Can you change the `Write-Verbose` to `Write-Host` and see how many execution cycles it goes through, please?

Comment: You mean this?

Den ID van het zoekveld is Element (id = 0.14751870639676423-1)
Den ID van het zoekveld is Element (id = 0.14751870639676423-2)
Den ID van de zoekknop is 
Den ID van de zoekknop is 
Den ID van de zoekknop is 
Exception calling "Click" with "0" argument(s): "stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=57.0.2987.133)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT 10.0.10586 x86_64)"

Comment: This suggests that the test in the while block is incorrect... I was _assuming_ that `FindElementByXPath` would return `$null` if there were no results... the documentation seems to suggest it would throw an exception; which it doesn't appear to be doing. So having a bit more of a read round it looks like you need to use a wait method. See here: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits-reference

Comment: Well now the While part does not generate an error, but the click is not executed.